# Can employees' personal properties be part of the scope?

Tags: penetration-test, physical, legal

Let's assume the customer (target) wants to have a full physical pentest done.

(I'm a student and have 0 exp in actual Pentesting and Red Teaming

Properties of topic:

- Cars (in the car park)
- Personal laptops
- Phones
- Physical documents
- "password notebooks" (of people who are just ASKING to get hacked)

The above items are personal properties of the employees, not owned by the company (target). The target company may say "We'd like to include the staff's properties in the scope" (I'm not sure if people would actually say that, but let's assume they do). Can such properties be considered part of the scope? Can we "borrow" those items or take things (data, stuff in a car) from them as flags or just get possible data and passwords from them to further the engagement? (I'm not sure that'd be legal)

Comment: Like your other questions, you need to first think about the ***legal, moral, and ethical*** implications. You don't need pentesting experience for that.

Comment: I did think and thought it was mostly an obvious "NO" but there are some people who will just make ridiculous requests as such. Just wanted to confirm.

Comment: No, they won't make this request.

Answer (score 3):

An obvious...

## no.

You cannot break into private property and/or steal any form of belongings  unless authorized to do so. Authorized, that is, by the **owner(s)** of the property. This includes non-invasive/non-damaging methods. Your local laws regarding the protection of property apply to the employees as much as to the stranger on the street.

The company does not own their employees private belongings, so they have no authority over the same. If you want to break into an employee's private car, for example, you need their express permission.

I'm not a lawyer neither work in this field, but this one was obvious.

Comment: I do think it's always a "no" but I just wanna REALLY make sure, leaving no "may be"

Comment: There is absolutely no question, this is common sense, and it would border insanity to think anything else. You always need the permission of the owner to "break into their property and steal their belongings" (even if it's done without breaking things)